# Dimension reduction for logical arrays

Tags: dimensionality-reduction

I have measurements of 4 devices at two different points of time. A measurement basically consists of an array of ones and zeros corresponding to a bit value at the corresponding location:

```
whos measurement1_dev1_time1

Name                         Size               Bytes  Class      Attributes

measurement1_dev1_time1      4096x8             32768  logical
```

I assume that for a specific device the changes between time 1 and 2 of the measurements are unique. However, since I am dealing with 32768 bits at different locations, it is quite hard to visualize if there is some kind of dependency.

As every bit at location `x`can be regarded as one dimension of an observation I thought to use PCA to reduce the number of dimensions.

Thus, for every of the 5 devices:

1. I randomly sample `n` measurements at point `t1`and `t2` seperatly
2. I prepare an array as input for `pca()` with `m`*n columns (`m`< 32768; its a subset of all the observed bits, as the original data might be too big for pca) and 4 rows (one row for each device).
3. On this array `A` I calculate the pca: ``[coeff score latent] = pca(zscore(A))```
4. Then I try to visualize it using `biplot`: `biplot(coeff(:,1:2), 'score', score(:,1:2))`

However, this gives me really strange results. Maybe PCA is not the right approach for this problem? I also modified the input data to do the PCA not on the logical bit array itself. Instead, I created a vector, which holds the indices where there is a '1' in the original measurement array. Also this produces strange results.

As I am completely new to PCA I want to ask you if you either see a flaw in the process or if PCA is just not the right approach for my goal and I better look for other dimension reduction approaches or clustering algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Standard PCA only sees your data as real values and hence doesn't really provide the best low rank approximation. There exist versions of PCA designed for boolean data types. Personally I think the best paper covering the whole broad topic of generalised PCA is [Generalized Low Rank Models](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/glrm.pdf). In section 5.2 they specifically cover Boolean PCA.